Protection still adequate?
I'm trying to protect an analog input (that goes through a MUX and a buffering op amp). Expected input frequency is less than 10 Hz.
I would like to go from the top schema to the bottom one.

LDR/Photodiode are external to the PCB and could be 30m away from it, worst case on non shielded wires.
So far everything has been going OK.
(The schema is not quite correct, the 2 diodes are actually a BAT54S)
The reason for moving the voltage divider is that down the road, I plan on adding another MUX that will let me choose the voltage divider resistance. This mux would then be after the input protection.
My main reference is this: Article about protecting inputs and reading various forums.
Original reason for having 5k resistors everywhere was to lower the number of parts.
Am I missing anything or am I right to think the input protection will still be about the same?
